# Removing MouseListener produces ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, events, exception, mouselistener

Im getting "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0
and I really dont understand why.

I have these two inner classes that I use as Listeners for a JPanel called `bildYta`:

```
private class NyPlatsLyss implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        bildYta.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
        bildYta.addMouseListener(new BildYtaLyss());
        bildYta.addKeyListener(new EscLyss());
        bildYta.requestFocusInWindow();
        enableOperations(false);
    }
}

private class EscLyss extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            bildYta.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
            bildYta.removeMouseListener(bildYta.getMouseListeners()[0]);
            bildYta.removeKeyListener(this);
            enableOperations(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I press a button it adds both of the listeners to `bildYta`. What I do not understand is why I get .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0 when I remove the mouse listener that I just added. Sometimes I dont even get an exception, and sometimes I do. Nothing in the rest of my code should cause any trouble because after I add those listeners, nothing else is supposed to happen in my program. It waits for either and ESC press or a mouse click

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), sure there could be/is/are another issue(s), but become after Mouse events fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very fragile code. The event handled by `EscLyss` may fire several times and only the first time it will work. Add some checks to your code. Even better, save your `EscLyss` instance to a field and then remove that specific instance directly. Better still, make that instance final and you can reuse it, repeatedly adding and removing it as needed. That is, in fact, the way we typically do it.

```
private final MouseListener bildYtaLyss = new BildYtaLyss();

private class NyPlatsLyss implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    bildYta.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
    bildYta.addMouseListener(bildYtaLyss);
    EscLyss escLyss = new EscLyss();
    bildYta.addKeyListener(escLyss);
    bildYta.requestFocusInWindow();
    enableOperations(false);
  }
}

private class EscLyss extends KeyAdapter{
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
      bildYta.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
      bildYta.removeMouseListener(bildYtaLyss);
      bildYta.removeKeyListener(this);
      enableOperations(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im very new to programming so Im not sure I understand everything you said. But ill try make some kind of check that prevents it from fire more then once

Comment: Ok I tried adding a boolean that I set to true after it has fired, it didnt really help. But when I added `System.out.println(bildYta.getMouseListeners()[0]);` before I remove it it prints a mouse listener and it seems to fail less often

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I realise that creating new listeners and removing them all the time might be very unnecessary, I should disable them instead I think

Comment: BTW using anonymous classes makes this pattern even simpler to use. Read up on those. If you had these two listeners as anonymous class instances inside the method that builds the gui, the variable `bildYtaLyss` wouldn't need to be an instance field.

Answer (score 1):

Surround the removing code in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`